# remove white space from map when using proc gmap

Tags: sas

I'm using the following code in sas:

```
goptions reset=all border ;
goptions colors=(yellow steel purple pink red blue cyan orange green gray 
black);

title1 "Congo";
title2 "11 Regions";
footnote j=r "Congo ";


proc gmap map=mapsgfk.dr_congo data=mapsgfk.dr_congo all density=6;
 id id1;  
 choro id1/discrete;run;
quit;
```

and it generates the following map:[image]

How do I remove the white space inside some of the regions?

Comment: My first inclination is to believe that there is an issue of "order" of the dataset records (i.e., all the right points are there, but they're misordered, so it misdraws the points and leaves spaces).  I suspect there's a difference in using MAPSGFK vs MAPS in what exactly you have to do here, but I'm afraid I'm not sufficiently well versed in PROC GMAP to know what that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map data is segmented at the ID level.  The ID1 value is a truncation of ID.  The 'white-space' is due to a segment being associated to an id it does not belong to.  Try:

```
proc gmap 
  map=mapsgfk.dr_congo data=mapsgfk.dr_congo all density=6
;

  * simpler statements per DCR comment, removed format;
  id id;
  choro id1 / discrete;
run;
quit;
```

I believe there may still be some issues regarding lakes being drawn with a color.

Comment: well this works but your comment format does not affect id value  seems off.  without the format change things don't get drawn correctly.  Another solution is: id id; choro id1 /discrete;